# Permitir mostrar o meu site wordpress num iframe noutro site

Tags: wordpress, iframe, http-headers

Olá, 
Tenho um site em wordpress que gostava de mostrar uma das páginas num iframe num outro site, é possível fazer isso?
Neste momento ao fazer o iframe noutra página está me a parecer o seguinte erro:

"Refused to display 'https://meusite.pt/pagina_a_ser_renderizada' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

Não sei onde possa desativar a opção X-Frame-option.

Alguém me pode dar uma luz?

Obrigado

Comment: pode dizer qual a razao de usar iframe ? porque nao redirecionar para a pagina que quer apresentar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**X-Frame-Options**

O X-Frame-Options é usado para indicar ao navegador se ele está autorizado ou não a processar uma página em um frame, iframe ou object.

As três possíveis diretivas para X-Frame-Options são:

- X-Frame-Options: DENY
- X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
- X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM url-do-site-origem

**DENY:** A página não pode ser exibida em um frame.

**SAMEORIGIN:** A página pode ser exibida em um frame mas a origem deve ser o próprio site.

**ALLOW-FROM *uri*:** A página pode ser exibida em um frame se a origem for especificada.

Enfim, para que você tenha êxito em exibir o conteúdo de outro site em um iframe você deve alterar a diretiva para:

**ALLOW-FROM https://meusite.pt/pagina_a_ser_renderizada**

Provavelmente a opção atual deve estar configurada como **X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN**

Essa opção pode ser configurada no seu servidor web ou no header da página onde deseja exibir ou não o iframe.

Exemplos:

Tag Header: x-frame-options: ALLOW-FROM url-do-site-origem

Apache: adicione ao httpd.conf: header always set x-frame-options "ALLOW-FROM url-do-site-origem"